# Are there any cscope or ctags APIs that can be used programmatically?

Tags: ctags, cscope

I have been using ctags and cscope for sometime now. I wanted to know if there exist any APIs so as to grab output of "cscope -d". Or maybe if we can use cscope.out and tags database to extract readable information.

Answer (score 0):

[libreadtags](https://github.com/universal-ctags/libreadtags) is a library for reading a "tags" file generated by ctags.
If `--sort=yes` is specified as the command line of ctags invocation, libreadtags can do binary-search.

Comment: Is there any documentation or "code snippets" examples I can refer for this library?

Comment: see https://github.com/universal-ctags/libreadtags/issues/30